# running Python 3 in chrome on Windows 8 computer

Tags: windows, python-3.x, google-chrome, browser

I have seen other programmers running their code in chrome and I want to do the same with my python 3 programs, but when I follow tutorials I always get an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, browsers (chrome or most others) only run javascript code, but not Python code. Python code runs in an interpreter. There are some third party websites that lets you type in some code, but I don't think any of them are great. If you tried one of them, please provide the website and the code you used and the error you got.

'an error message' is never useful. Please detail the particular error you are getting, and any traceback when available..

Comment: Thank you for saving me time

Comment: You are welcome. But next time you post a question, give a few more specifics. If you get an error, mention which error you are getting and in what part of your code. Python provides nice Traceback for errors, so you can copy-paste the whole error message and traceback. This way, it will be easier for others to understand your problem and help you.